# SPARK RDD Between logic using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to check a between logic using 2 RDD's. I am not able to figure out how I can do that

```
RDD1 :
Type: Array[(String, Long)]]
Array(("EMP1",0),("EMP2",1),("EMP3",2),("EMP4",3),("EMP5",4),("EMP6",5),("EMP7",6),("EMP8",7))



RDD2 :
Type :Array[Array[Any]]
Array([0,3,ABC],[3,5,XYZ],[5,1000,PQR])
```

I want to check the range logic like

I want to get output like:
 for each element in RDD1, check  if RDD1.x._2(Gives the long value)  is between RDD2.X._1 and RDD2.x._2 (BETWEEN LOGIC).
 If it is present, then concatenate the value from RDD2

Sample Final Output:

```
 Array[("EMP1 ABC",0),("EMP2 ABC",1),("EMP3 ABC",2),("EMP4 XYZ",3),("EMP5 XYZ",4),("EMP6 PQR",5),("EMP7 PQR",6),("EMP8 PQR",7)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create input rdd 
val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array(("EMP1",0),("EMP2",1),("EMP3",2),("EMP4",3),("EMP5",4),("EMP6",5),("EMP7",6),("EMP8",7)))
val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array((0,3,"ABC"),(3,5,"XYZ"),(5,1000,"PQR")))

// 1. perform a cross join/cartesian, the rdd looks like (("EMP1",0), (0,3,"ABC"))
// 2. filter out those records which are not within range
// 3. formatting 
rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
    .filter(record => record._1._2 >= record._2._1 && record._1._2 < record._2._2)
    .map(record => (record._1._1 + " " + record._2._3, record._1._2))
    .collect().foreach(println(_))

// result
(EMP1 ABC,0)
(EMP2 ABC,1)
(EMP3 ABC,2)
(EMP4 XYZ,3)
(EMP5 XYZ,4)
(EMP6 PQR,5)
(EMP7 PQR,6)
(EMP8 PQR,7)
```

updated the between logic from [  ] to [  )

Thanks

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks Li. For small data sets this is fine. But, I have rdd1 with 2 Million  elements.I hope it won't cause any issue.But, I can give this a try.

Comment: " hope it won't cause any issue." The result of the `cartesian` will have 4 thousand billion elements. Might be an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Dataframe`s or `Dataset`s as they are optimized version of `rdd` with more functionality.

So you have to change the `rdd`s to `dataframe`s as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df1 = rdd1.toDF("name1", "num")
val df2 = rdd2.toDF("start", "end", "name2")
```

And finally use `join` and `select` methods to get the final result you require

```
df1.join(broadcast(df2), df2("start") <= df1("num") && df2("end") > df1("num"))
  .select("name1", "name2", "num")
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-----+---+
|name1|name2|num|
+-----+-----+---+
|EMP1 |ABC  |0  |
|EMP2 |ABC  |1  |
|EMP3 |ABC  |2  |
|EMP4 |XYZ  |3  |
|EMP5 |XYZ  |4  |
|EMP6 |PQR  |5  |
|EMP7 |PQR  |6  |
|EMP8 |PQR  |7  |
+-----+-----+---+
```

Now you can change it back to `rdd` using `.rdd`

Or you can continue processing using `dataframes` itself

I hope the answer is helpful